# In Scala, how does one determine the import path from the dependency name?

Tags: scala

While adding a dependency to a Play 2.2 application written in Scala, it has occurred to me that I have no idea how the import path is actually defined or where to find it.

For example, I added this dependency to my Build.scala file, like so:

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
  "nl.rhinofly" %% "play-s3" % "4.0.0",
  ...
)
```

Looking at this, I would assume that the import would be of 'nl.rhinofly.play_s3'; and when I look in my cache, that seems to confirm this thinking:

```
/home/immauser/.ivy2/cache/nl.rhinofly/play-s3_2.10
```

However, this import errors on compile with 'nl not found':

```
import nl.rhinofly.play_s3._
```

However, this works:

```
import fly.play.s3._
```

My question is: given just the dependency and the material in the cache, how would one go about determining that the correct import path is "fly.play.s3._"? where does one look to find this data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR**: you *cannot* determine the import path from the dependency group and name - the two are unrelated. Any correlation between the two is the result of a *convention* for naming Jars, but it isn't enforced in any way, isn't always adhered to, and certainly cannot be assumed.

**Details**:

1. First, this behavior has nothing to do with Play, and isn't even specific to Scala, it's inherited from the way Java class names work and the way maven repositories name jar dependencies
2. The *"import path"* is actually the "fully-qualified" class name, which is simply the name of the class preceded by the folders that contain it *within the jar* (any of the jars in your classpath) separated by dots. The *jar name* has nothing to do with this
3. Any jar can contain any class, and two different jars can contain instances of two classes with the same fully-qualified name (not a desirable situation)

What you *can* do is inspect the contents of a given jar, either within any modern IDE (e.g. IntelliJ, Eclipse) or using command line `jar tf`, e.g.:

```
$ jar tf ~/.ivy2/cache/org.mockito/mockito-core/jars/mockito-core-1.9.5.jar
```

The result would be a list of all files in the jar, for example:

```
...
org/mockito/Answers.class
org/mockito/Answers.java
org/mockito/ArgumentCaptor.class
org/mockito/ArgumentCaptor.java
org/mockito/ArgumentMatcher.class
org/mockito/ArgumentMatcher.java
...
```

The `*.class` files can technically be imported (although some of these classes might be private or package-protected; Only the public ones can be used).

Comment: jar tf is precisely what i was seeking!